# How to run specific Activity first?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-activity, android-debug

I'm writing android app and currently debugging some functionality which runs on **Activity X**.
**Activity X** depends on some value from **Activity Y**, which depends on **Activity B**, which runs when I click *button* on **Main Activity**.

It's really painful to:

1. change code
2. re-run app
3. click on button on Main Act, enter some text on Act B, chose value from spinner on Act. Y
4. debug function
5. --> 1. change code

Is there some faster way to run **Activity X** with parameters I get from *getExtras()*?
IDE I using is Eclipse, actually it's Android Developer Tools.

Comment: Could just put some temporary dummy variables at the top of Activity X set to what you want them to be and comment out the part where you are actually pulling those variables from a bundle from Activity Y.

Comment: I have this situation often. Is this 'trick' really a solution?

Comment: Ideal and best, probably not, but a solution yes :) That's why I left it as a comment.

Comment: So, each time you need to debug some Activity, you hardcode parameters and change in manifest to start first?

Answer (score 0):

use the class like this and run the class from activity A like this :

class B :

```
public class UpdateUtils { 


}
    public void update {
  // your sample code
```

}
and call it from activity A :

```
private final UpdateUtils updateUtils = UpdateUtils.getInstance();
 updateUtils.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

put startActivity() in on resume method with pre filled data in intent
OR
change intent filter in android manifest of that activity to launcher activity